# Where can closed, more opinionated but still juridical, questions be asked?

Tags: discussion

[This helpful answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/9269/why-does-duncan-kennedy-opine-legal-services-practice-far-more-fun-intellectual) motivates:

1. The question entitled above.
2. and whether closed, more opinionated but still juridical, questions can be discussed on Law Meta SE, per the bolded below.

> However, the answer to a question like the fourth [...] [https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/9269/why-does-duncan-kennedy-opine-legal-services-practice-far-more-fun-intellectual] doesn't have any basis in law.  We'd then ask, does it have any basis in fact or the application of facts to laws?  In this example, X states mere personal opinion, albeit based on interesting observations.  This seems better suited to a book club or discussion group since it would be hard to craft an answer that brings out the nuances without in-depth knowledge of non-law/fact aspects of secondary sources.
>
> **That brings up a second rule-of-thumb: *is the question better suited to a* [discussion](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) *tag?*  If so, we don't have such a tag on Law.SE...just on Meta, at which point we could ask whether it belongs on Meta in the first place.**

Answer (score 7):

Not here.

*Meta* sites are for problems and questions *regarding the underlying site*.

Meta sites are *not* for asking and answering questions that one would like to put on the underlying site but that are off-topic or closed.  (Though they are appropriate places to ask for clarification about *why* things are off-topic.)

The only place I can think of in the Stack Exchange world where real "discussions" can take place is [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24153/the-sidebar).

Comment: ... and sadly, it's not always the case that we can find _every_ question a home on the SE Network of Q&A sites. You're free to explore the 120+ other Stack Exchange sites if you insist on this format, but perhaps another type of website is more suited for you.

Answer (score 1):

The entire *raison d'être* of Stackexchange sites is to provide a venue where people can obtain specific factual information. Just because a question is about law doesn't mean that the question is suitable for here. There are other venues structured to allow discussion, for example expertlaw.com, lawyers.com, or forum.freeadvice.com. However, they are focused on actual legal problems, and not an interest in an author's motivation for choice of expression.